# Sending FCM notification using Cloud Functions .. Issue

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to send FCM notification through the Cloud functions but it's not working ...

Here is the code ...  I doubt that the path to the db is not correct!

```
var functions = require("firebase-functions");
let admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


exports.sendPush = functions.database.ref('/messages/{messageId}').onCreate(event => {

    let payload = {
        notification: {
            title: 'Firebase Notification',
            body: 'Coming from DB Trigger!',
            sound: 'default',
            badge: '1'
        }
    };

    let tokens = 'e28NuXH_8gY:APA91bGdDjb....';
    admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
});
```

Here is the database design:

[DB Image ONE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPXte.png)

[DB Image TWO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BopO0.png)

Comment: Remove `sound` and `badge` from the `notification` payload.  Also, change the last line to `return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload).catch(console.log);`

Comment: Also, shouldn't `tokens` be an array of string ids?

Comment: @JamesPoag - Tried your suggestion but still, the notification is not coming! 
I hardcoded the token to just test - Also when I change the Db trigger with HTTP it's working fine. So, I think the issue is not related to the cloud messaging part of the code!